# Terminal: cp -r with directories with same name and different case

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, cp

I'm trying to copy around ~250Gb from one drive to another. Catch is that the destination drive is formatted in NTFS or FAT or something and isn't case-sensitive, and I've got folders I need to copy across that are named like so:

```
FolderOne
folderone
```

I don't care if I *merge* the directories, but I don't want to lose any data. Any help?

Comment: `cp -i -r` will prompt before overwriting

Answer (score 0):

What worked best for me was:

```
ditto /Source/ /Destination/
```

Perfect.